Set cookies for 2 areas in .NET Core 8
I have a project and I have designed 2 areas: one for the users of my site and one for the management panel. Customers must login and admin users must also login. I don't want anyone to enter the site or admin panel without permission.
I have to restrict access. Cookies must be set for both areas. How to use two areas in .NET Core 8 and set cookies for both areas?
app.MapAreaControllerRoute(
    name: "Admin",
    areaName: "Admin",
    pattern: "Admin/{controller=Login}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapAreaControllerRoute(
    name: "Customer",
    areaName: "Customer",
    pattern: "Customer/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");


In .NET it is not possible to secure controllers based on Areas.
Instead, you could create a base controller that defines the authorization requirements for a specific area. Now the only thing you have to do is ensure that an area's controllers inherit from their respective base controller.
Firstly create an authorization policy to apply to the base controller, with this policy we can make sure a user is authenticated using one of your cookie schemes:
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AdminOnly", policy =>
    {
        policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(AdminCookieSchemeName);
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
    });
}

After that we can create a controller and apply the AuthorizationPolicy:
[Authorize("AdminOnly")]
public class AdminAreaController : Controller
{
    // Actions
}

Now you can create a Home Controller for admins only by doing this:
public class HomeController : AdminAreaController
{
    // Actions
}

Here is a link to .NET documentation:

Policy-based authorization: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-8.0

I know this is not the solution you'd hoped for, but this makes it quite easy to define "area"-wide behaviour.
Hopefully, this helps!

You could set cookie path to restrict to one path prefix. But unfortunately, this doesn't support 2 separate paths. An easy solution is to add a prefix to both the Admin and Customer area route.
app.MapAreaControllerRoute(
    name: "Admin",
    areaName: "Admin",
    pattern: "User/Admin/{controller=Login}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapAreaControllerRoute(
    name: "Customer",
    areaName: "Customer",
    pattern: "User/Customer/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

Then you could configure the cookie only pass to URL with prefix "/user".
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("mycookie")
    .AddCookie("mycookie",options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Path= "/user";
    });

If you are using asp.net core identity, it will be
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Path = "/user";
});

